# systemd: ignore accidental power button pressses

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

On my laptop (Acer C720P) the power button is a regular keyboard key that I accidentally press all the time. This shuts down my computer instantly. Following somebody's advice, I disabled the power key using logind.conf. Now the power key is completely ignored which means it is more inconvenient to shut down my computer. Is there any way to set Arch so that the power button is ignored unless it is pressed for more than a second?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/362914/how-to-prevent-the-power-button-to-shutdown-directly-the-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `xev` what event is emitted when pressing power off button. In my case was a `XF86PowerOff`.

I simply added a global hotkey to my window manager (AwesomeWM) which runs a little bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

zenity --question --text "Power off?" --default-cancel && poweroff
```

After that my system is asking me what to do when I'm pressing power off button.

Comment: how did you manage to add the new global hotkey?

Comment: I added this in `.config/awesome/rc.lua`: `awful.key({ }, "XF86PowerOff", function () awful.util.spawn(home .. "/.config/awesome/scripts/powerbutton") end),
` , created your script in `~/.config/awesome/scripts/powerbutton` but still, the powerbutton immediately powers down the laptop!

Comment: Also:  *"Check with xev what event is emitted when pressing power off button"* Ha! Ha! - How should I check it with this? the Laptop immediately shuts down then ;)

Comment: @rubo77 So I am very sorry, but mine laptops never shuts down immediately. I must press poweroff for at least 4 secs. You may have shortcut bound to the button already.

Comment: And probably yours button will emit XF86PowerOff, too. You don't have to use xev, I guess.

Comment: If I start Ubuntu Unity on the same laptop, I can check with `xev` [this is the output there](http://paste.toppoint.de/?6e01bc7226e07971#eKnewYex1P3ilcHqf9oLcy6zGf18seZ5kiClFJS+54Y=)